# Run CountDownTimer inside CoroutineWorker

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

I am developing a registration form with kotlin in android and after several failed attempts I need to block the form for a while, be it an hour or 30 minutes and that the service runs in the background so the app closes or destroys

After consulting and reading the android documentation, I am solving this problem with workmanager by extending the CoroutineWorker() class, but I find the following problem that does not let me proceed:

```
Can't create handler inside thread Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1,5,main] that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

***ViewModel that invokes the CoroutineWorker***

```
    @HiltViewModel
class RegisterViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val registerUseCase: RegisterUseCase
) : ViewModel() {
    
        fun makeApiPost(
                context: Context,
                card: String,
                .... : ...
            )
        {

            viewModelScope.launch {
                val retroInstance = RetroInstance.getRetroInstanceAuth(context).create(
                    RetroService::class.java
                )
                val call = retroInstance.getGiftCardBalance(
                    CardBalanceRequest(card, ..., ...)
                )
                call.enqueue(object : Callback<BalanceResponse> {
                    override fun onResponse(
                        call: Call<BalanceResponse>,
                        response: Response<AppBalanceResponse>
                    ) {

                        if (response.isSuccessful) {
                            val destination = response.body()
                            destination?.let {
                                _cardBalance.postValue(response.body()!!.payload.data)
                            }
                        } else {

                            val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(ExtendedApp.myContext)
                            workManager.enqueue(OneTimeWorkRequest.from(WorkerActivate::class.java))

                            _cardBalance.postValue(null)
                        }

                    }

                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<CardBalanceResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                        t.printStackTrace()
                        _cardBalance.postValue(null)
                        call.request()
                    }
                })
            }
        }
}
```

***Background process***

```
    class WorkerActivate(context: Context, workerParameters: WorkerParameters) : CoroutineWorker(
        context, workerParameters
    )
    {
    
        lateinit var countDownTimer: CountDownTimer
    
        override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
            
            val minutesTimer: Long =  (60 * 1000 * 30)

            countDownTimer =  object : CountDownTimer(minutesTimer, 1000){
                override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                    Log.d("card", "Counting Down: ${millisUntilFinished/1000}")
                }
    
                override fun onFinish() {
                    Log.i("card", "countDownTimer de 15 segundos ok")
                }
            }
            
            return Result.success()
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

in your code 13 line is the problem. WorkManager can only be started from the Main thread and that`s the reason you are getting this error.

```
viewModelScope.launch {
<<< This area is sub Thread >>>
}

// Try this...
withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
    val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(ExtendedApp.myContext)
    workManager.enqueue(OneTimeWorkRequest.from(WorkerActivate::class.java))
}
```